# Не могу корректно добавить список в "список списков"?

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

Имею ArrayList из него нужно получить все возможные перестановки и варианты загнать в "список списков".

Т.е. ожидаю:

> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2], [2, 1], [2, 1, 3],
>   [2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3], [3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]

Как бы все просто и очевидно но получаю:

> [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3,
>   2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2,
>   1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]

Что я недопонимаю?

```
packag com.mytest.Rekursija;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Created by bigvova on 18.09.15.
 */
class Permutation {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addToListOfLists(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
        if (!array.isEmpty()) listOfLists.add(array);
    }

    public void permute(ArrayList<Integer> done, ArrayList<Integer> remaining) {
        addToListOfLists(done);
        if (remaining.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<>(remaining);
        Collections.sort(sorted);
        for (int j = 0; j < remaining.size(); j++) {
            Integer c = sorted.get(j);
            remaining.remove(c);
            done.add(c);
            permute(done, remaining);
            done.remove(c);
            remaining.add(0, c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> remaining = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        ArrayList<Integer> done = new ArrayList<>();
        Permutation permutation = new Permutation();
        permutation.permute(done, remaining);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете всегда один и тот же список `done` в результат, а потом продолжаете модифицировать его. В результате вы просто имеете один и тот же объект много раз в `listOfLists`, в его последнем состоянии. Чтобы исправить это, достаточно снять копию здесь:

```
addToListOfLists(new ArrayList<>(done));
```